# Acessing data from numpy array to plot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I'm an engineering student trying to learn python. I was wondering how you access points in a numpy array in order to plot them.

```
joints = numpy.array([[0,5],[0,0],[10,0],[20,0]])
bars = numpy.array([[False,True,True,True],[True,False,True,False], \
                    [True,True,False,True],[True,False,True,False]])
```

I know how to plot points in general, I'm just unsure how I would access all the x points and y points individually to plot them and then access the data in bars to graph the bar between the joints.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to access each x,y coordinate of `joints`? I think you might be looking for a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

joints = np.array([[0,5],[0,0],[10,0],[20,0]])

for x in joints:
    print(x)
```

x should now be a reference to each point in the joints array and you can do whatever you want with them? In your case plot them.